# Java - getServletContext().getAttribute() returns null

Tags: java, servlets

I have a `MainServletContext` that `implements ServletContextListener` that stores an attribute

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();

    // successfully get a non-null stockMap
    servletContext.setAttribute("stockMap", stockMap);
}
```

I declared it in `web.xml`, it looks like

```
  <listener>
        <listener-class>controller.MainServletContext</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Now I want to get this `stockMap` back from a servlet class

```
Map<SimpleStock, Stock> stockMap = (Map<SimpleStock, Stock>) getServletContext().getAttribute("stockMap");
```

I got a `NullPointerException`. May I ask if there's any step missing?

Thanks.

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)
controller.TopTenServlet.service(TopTenServlet.java:91)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

My Servlet init method

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.servletConfig = config;
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've overridden your `init(ServletConfig)` method incorrectly. It should be

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config); // would set: this.config = config;
    this.servletConfig = config;
}
```

This is why it's ***not*** recommended to override `init(ServletConfig)` but the `init()` convenience method as it prevents the exact same problem you've run into.

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    this.servletConfig = config;
}
```

The base class `GenericServlet#init(ServletConfig)` would call your `init()` as

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.config = config;
    this.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a servlet init(ServletConfig config) method that doesn't call super(config).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added my init method in the OP